# Edit soap response C#

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

i have a visual studio web service and one of the [WebMethod] returns an array object like this:

```
        public createSerial[] Create(string inputSerial)
    {
        Bus bus = new Bus();
        return bus.CreateOperation()
    }
```

when i call it it generates the following response:

```
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <CreateSerial xmlns="http://london.com/v1/">
         <CreateSerialRequestResult>
            <CreateSerialResponse>
               <serial xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/ve">57</serial>
            </CreateSerialResponse>
         </CreateSerialRequestResult>
      </CreateSerial>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

but i want only this :

```
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <CreateSerial xmlns="http://london.com/v1/">
               <serial>57</serial>
      </CreateSerial>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare
```